# how to save req.body and req.file at same form

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

i have a form that have file input and text input

```
<form action ='/admin-panel' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type='text' name='title'/>
<textarea name='content'></textarea>
<input type="file" name="picture">
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

i can save title and content fields in my mongoDB , also i can save my file at my dest `/uploads`

here is the code :

```
app.post('/admin-panel',upload.single('picture'),function(req,res){


db.collection('articles').save(req.body,function (err,result){
if(err){return console.log(err)}
    else{
      console.log(req.file.filename) // form files
    console.log(req.body.title) // form files

        res.redirect('/admin-panel');
    }
});
})
```

the question is how to save req.file.filename into my db ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Object spread operator, like this:

```
app.post('/admin-panel',upload.single('picture'),function(req,res){


db.collection('articles').save({filename:req.file.filename,...req.body},function (err,result){
if(err){return console.log(err)}
    else{
      console.log(req.file.filename) // form files
    console.log(req.body.title) // form files

        res.redirect('/admin-panel');
    }
});
})
```

See `({filename:req.file.filename,...req.body})` it will give you an object that contain the filename and all the properties from `req.body`.

Just a security recommendation, be sure what users send in the body, they might overwrite the req.file.filename in the request body. So my recommendation is to change it to: `({...req.body,req.file.filename})`, this way the filename from req.file will take precedence over the same field if exist in `req.body`

*Read more about it:*

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax